# Sylow system of a group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a finite group with distinct prime divisors $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$. If $Q_i$ is the Hall $p_i'$-subgroup of $G$, then the set $\sum = \{Q_1, Q_2, \ldots, Q_k\}$ is a *Sylow System* of $G$.

> Suppose that $H\leq G$. Then $\sum \cap H := \{K \cap H \,|\, K \in \sum \}$ is not necessarily a Sylow system of $H$. I need to find a counterexample to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be a conjugate of $Q_1$ that is not equal to $Q_1$.

Comment: Why would such a counterexample work? Is it is because $Q_1 \cap H$ is a not a Hall subgroup of $H$?

Comment: The Hall subgroup (p-Sylow subgroup) of $H$ would be $H$ itself. But $Q_1 \bigcap H$ is not $H$ if $H$ is a conjugate of $Q_1$ not equal to $Q_1$.

Answer (score 0):

suppose G ia finite group and o(G)=(p^m)n where p is prime .If p^m|o(G) and p^(m+1) is not a divisor of o(G) then G is a subgroup of p^m

Comment: Please refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for mathJax formatting